# openAi gym for python linux debain

Tags: python, debian, python-3.6, python-module, openai-gym

I am having a problem with openAi gym, 
I install it with the command:

```
> pip install gym
```

but when I tried to run the program called cig3.py:

```
import gym
env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
env.reset()
for _ in range(1000):
    env.render()
    env.step(env.action_space.sample())
```

I get that message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cig3.py", line 1, in <module>
    import gym
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gym'
```

I am working in this version:

```
Linux mgdebian 4.9.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.88-1+deb9u1 (2018-05-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and with Python 3.6.4
does anyone know what the problem?

Comment: Was the installation successful? Please run `pip freeze | grep gym`. It will list all installed packages and check for gym. If there is no output it means the gym is not installed.

Comment: this is what i gut: 
gym==0.10.5 
but when i tried to install it again it says gym already installed

Comment: Are you running the code with `python your_script.py` or `python3 your_script.py`? Python2 modules are installed with `pip` command while Python3 modules are installed with `pip3` command.

Comment: the massage that i get when i tried pip3:
 command not found: pip3

Comment: It worked for me. However, I can see a couple of people struggling like you do, check out their solutions:
https://github.com/dennybritz/reinforcement-learning/issues/56

https://github.com/stevenpjg/ddpg-aigym/issues/9